# Kernel Module Upgrade

Tags: linux, radeon

Due to historical reason, I am bound to use kernel 3.0 for my existing custom operating system.

Now, I'm trying to use this OS onto new board, which requires `radeon` kernel module for native X driver to start the GUI.

Problem is that, required `radeon` do not support the intended chipset board.

But the same kernel driver of 3.12 do support the said chipset.

How can I compile 3.12's (for argument) radeon kernel module against 3.0 ?

[ One way is to replace source directory `/usr/src/3.12/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon` at `/usr/src/3.0/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon`. Though, I haven't tried this, will try it. ]

Answer (score 1):

There are several online resources for building out of tree kernel modules; e.g.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x181.html

If these are too old, you can try this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/168279/how-do-i-build-a-single-in-tree-kernel-module

and adapt the instructions to the distro you are using.

You should be able to take the 3.12 source for this module and build it as an out of tree module for your particular system.  Just make sure that you compile it using the system you plan to load the module on.